# TensorFlow Extended data_accessor.tf_dataset_factory() shape discrepancies

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, parquet, tfx

I am facing a perplexing issue while attempting to convert a vanilla tensorflow/keras workflow into a tensorflow extended pipeline.

In short: the datasets generated using tfx’s [ExampleGen](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/examplegen) component have different shapes from those created manually using `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()` from the same data, and cannot be fed into a keras model.

### Reproducible example

#### 1. Data generation

Let’s assume we create a sample dataset using:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [float(x) for x in range(100)],
    'b': [float(x + 1) for x in range(100)],
    'c': [float(x**2) for x in range(100)],
    'target': [random.randint(0, 2) for _ in range(100)],
})

df.to_parquet({my_path})
```

#### 2. Model generation

Let's use a dummy dense model for simplicity's sake.

```py
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD

def build_model():

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(8, input_shape=(3,), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(
        optimizer=SGD(),
        loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
        metrics=["sparse_categorical_accuracy"],
    )

    return model
```

#### 3. What works: manual dataset creation

This parquet file can then be loaded back into a pandas df and converted into a tensorflow dataset using:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

_BATCH_SIZE = 4

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    tf.cast(df[['a', 'b', 'c']].values, tf.float32),
    tf.cast(df['target'].values, tf.int32),
)).batch(_BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
```

This gives a dataset with `cardinality() = <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=25>`, which can be fed to the toy model above.

#### 4. What doesn't work: making a tensorflow extended pipeline

I have tried to replicate those results by applying a slightly modified tfx [starter pipeline](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/tfx/penguin_simple):

```py
from tfx_bsl.tfxio import dataset_options
from tfx.components import SchemaGen
from tfx.components import StatisticsGen
from tfx.components import Trainer
from tfx.dsl.components.base import executor_spec
from tfx.components.example_gen.component import FileBasedExampleGen
from tfx.components.example_gen.custom_executors import parquet_executor
from tfx.components.trainer.executor import GenericExecutor
from tfx.orchestration import metadata
from tfx.orchestration import pipeline
from tfx.proto import trainer_pb2
from tfx.proto import example_gen_pb2
from tfx.utils.io_utils import parse_pbtxt_file


_BATCH_SIZE = 4
_LABEL_KEY = 'target'
_EPOCHS = 10


def _input_fn(file_pattern, data_accessor, schema) -> Dataset:

    dataset = data_accessor.tf_dataset_factory(
        file_pattern,
        dataset_options.TensorFlowDatasetOptions(
            batch_size=_BATCH_SIZE,
            label_key=_LABEL_KEY,
            num_epochs=_EPOCHS,
        ),
        schema,
    )
    
    return dataset


def build_model():
    """Same as above"""

    ...

    return model


def run_fn(fn_args):
    schema = parse_pbtxt_file(fn_args.schema_file, schema_pb2.Schema())
    
    train_dataset = _input_fn(
        fn_args.train_files,
        fn_args.data_accessor,
        schema,
    )
    eval_dataset = _input_fn(
        fn_args.eval_files,
        fn_args.data_accessor,
        schema,
    )

    model = build_model()
    model.fit(
        train_dataset,
        steps_per_epoch=fn_args.train_steps,
        validation_data=eval_dataset,
        validation_steps=fn_args.eval_steps,
        epochs=_EPOCHS,
    )

    model.save(fn_args.serving_model_dir, save_format='tf')


def _create_pipeline(
    pipeline_name: str,
    pipeline_root: str,
    data_root: str,
    module_file: str,
    metadata_path: str,
    split: dict,
) -> pipeline.Pipeline:

    split_config = example_gen_pb2.SplitConfig(
        splits=[
            example_gen_pb2.SplitConfig.Split(name=name, hash_buckets=buckets)
            for name, buckets in split.items()
        ]
    )

    example_gen = FileBasedExampleGen(
        input_base=data_root,
        custom_executor_spec=executor_spec.ExecutorClassSpec(parquet_executor.Executor),
        output_config=example_gen_pb2.Output(split_config=split_config),
    )

    statistics_gen = StatisticsGen(examples=example_gen.outputs['examples'])
    infer_schema = SchemaGen(statistics=statistics_gen.outputs['statistics'])

    trainer = Trainer(
        module_file=module_file,
        custom_executor_spec=executor_spec.ExecutorClassSpec(GenericExecutor),
        examples=example_gen.outputs['examples'],
        schema=infer_schema.outputs['schema'],
        train_args=trainer_pb2.TrainArgs(),
        eval_args=trainer_pb2.EvalArgs()
    )

    components = [example_gen, statistics_gen, infer_schema, trainer]
    metadata_config = metadata.sqlite_metadata_connection_config(metadata_path)

    _pipeline = pipeline.Pipeline(
        pipeline_name=pipeline_name,
        pipeline_root=pipeline_root,
        components=components,
        metadata_connection_config=metadata_config,
    )

    return _pipeline
```

However, the dataset generated by ExampleGen has cardinality `tf.Tensor(-2, shape=(), dtype=int64)`, and gives the following error message when fed to the same model:

```
ValueError: Layer sequential expects 1 inputs, but it received 3 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor object at 0x7f40353373d0>, <tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor object at 0x7f4035337710>, <tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor object at 0x7f40352e3190>]
```

Importantly: the problem persists even when the data are stored as a `csv` file and read using `CsvExampleGen`, which makes the issue very unlikely to arise from the data themselves.

Also, batching the tfx output dataset has no effect on the results.

I’ve tried everything I could think of to no benefit. The relative obscurity of what's happening under tfx's hood doesn't help with the debugging either. Has anyone any idea of what the problem is?

#### Edit 1

Two points have come to my attention since writing this question:

- `data_accessor.tf_dataset_factory()` doesn't actually output a `tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.TensorSliceDataset`, but a `tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.PrefetchDataset` instead.
- There's actually a small bunch of as yet unanswered questions that look somewhat related to my problem discussing the pains of working with `PrefetchDataset`s:

[TFDS Audio Preprocessing PrefetchDataset Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64579137/tfds-audio-preprocessing-prefetchdataset-problems)

[How to feed tf.prefetch dataset into LSTM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66302936/how-to-feed-tf-prefetch-dataset-into-lstm)

[Change PrefetchDataset shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64978453/change-prefetchdataset-shapes)

Considering none of those questions have found an answer, and that the crux of the problem seems to be the lack of documentation regarding `PrefetchDataset`s and how to use them, I'll open an issue on tfx's board and see how it goes if this doesn't get answered here within a few days.

#### Edit 2: version and environment details

As requested by [TensorFlow Support](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11530462/tensorflow-support), here are the details regarding the versions of all my TensorFlow-related installs:

- **Core components**:

  - tensorflow==2.3.0
  - tfx==0.25.0
  - tfx-bsl==0.25.0
- **TensorFlow-related stuff**:

  - tensorflow-cloud==0.1.7
  - tensorflow-data-validation==0.25.0
  - tensorflow-datasets==3.0.0
  - tensorflow-estimator==2.3.0
  - tensorflow-hub==0.9.0
  - tensorflow-io==0.15.0
  - tensorflow-metadata==0.25.0
  - tensorflow-model-analysis==0.25.0
  - tensorflow-probability==0.11.0
  - tensorflow-serving-api==2.3.0
  - tensorflow-transform==0.25.0
- **Environment and other miscellaneous details:**

  - Python version: 3.7.9
  - OS: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
  - Running from an N1 GCP instance

Comment: Please mention the versions you are using for tfx and tensorflow.

Comment: Added in Edit 2 - thanks for looking into it

Comment: @TensorflowSupport any update on this issue?